# Dart undefined is not a function when assigning final field

Tags: dart

When I try to assign final field in constructor i get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error in chrom. When I remove the `final` word it works (I am transpiling dart into Chrome using dart2js). Can someone explain me why i can not assign that final field?

This works:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class FileToUploadSet {
    InputElement _fooElement;

    FileToUploadSet(Element motherElement) {
        this._input = motherElement.querySelector('#foo');
    }
}
```

This does not:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class FileToUploadSet {
    final InputElement _fooElement;

    FileToUploadSet(Element motherElement) {
        this._input = motherElement.querySelector('#foo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only assign to final fields where you declare the field or in the constructor initialization list

```dart
import 'dart:html';

class FileToUploadSet {
    final InputElement _fooElement; <== here you can assign to a final field
    final String someField

    FileToUploadSet(Element motherElement, /* here with this._fooElement */) 
    /* and here like */ : this._fooElement = 'someValue' {
        // but not in the constructor body.
        this._input = motherElement.querySelector('#foo');
    }
}
```